# C++ - bind() fails

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to learn networking in C++ and I'm trying to setup a simple demo where I open a TCP server on port 5000 and then immediately close it. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int port = 5000;
    std::cout << "Port: " << port << "\n";
    int socketdesc = socket(SOCK_STREAM, AF_INET, 0);

    if (socketdesc == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create socket description.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int opt = 1;

    if (setsockopt(socketdesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
               &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to attach socket.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(socketdesc, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
         sizeof(address)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to bind socket!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Listening with protocol TCP on port" << port << ".\n";

    if (listen(socketdesc, 3) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to listen!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (shutdown(socketdesc, SHUT_RDWR) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to close socket!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "TCP test succeeeded.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error when I try to bind the socket to the port 5000. What is going wrong with setting the TCP server port?

P.S: what exactly is the opt bit for (I'm following a tutorial and looking at the documentation for sys/socket at the same time)?

Comment: What is the value of `errno` after `bind` fails?

Comment: Always 22. I've tried comparing its value to some of the error numbers to returns according to documentation but none of them match. This is where I'm getting the error numbers from: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/bind.html

Comment: If something fails always check the return values/errno etc of what failed. For POSIX library functions the man pages are always very helpful. [Here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html#ERRORS) you can find the appropriate error codes for `bind()`. Im not sure but i think you can "stringify" that code with [strerror()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror)

Comment: strerror() returns "Invalid argument".

Comment: Shouldn't `socket(SOCK_STREAM, AF_INET, 0);` be `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`?  So you're calling `bind` against a bad descriptor value (-1 probably).

Comment: Yep, that was it. Just a stupid mistake on my part. By the way, what's the best place to look at C++ documentation? A site that's guaranteed to have to-date and detailed descriptions of classes/methods? I want to learn more C++.

Comment: @liaquore en.cppreference.com is detailed, current, and usually correct. (There are no guarantees on the web, though.)

Comment: Also note that according to [man pages for socket()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) `-1` is returned on error not `0`. So you propably would have cought the error before trying to bind right at the start.

Comment: @Yastanub same with [`setsockopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setsockopt.3p.html) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code before you even reach `bind()`:

> int socketdesc = socket(SOCK_STREAM, AF_INET, 0);

You have the first 2 parameter values backwards, the call needs to look like this instead:

```
int socketdesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

> if (socketdesc == 0)

`socket()` returns -1 on error, not 0.

> if (setsockopt(socketdesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)))

`setsockopt()` also returns -1 on error.

But more importantly, you can't combine multiple socket options in a single call like this.  You need to call `setsockopt()` for each option individually:

```
if (setsockopt(socketdesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
...

if (setsockopt(socketdesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
...
```

With that said, try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int port = 5000;
    std::cout << "Port: " << port << "\n";

    int socketdesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (socketdesc == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create socket descriptor. " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int opt = 1;

    if (setsockopt(socketdesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to set SO_REUSEADDR option. " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(socketdesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to set SO_REUSEPORT option. " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(socketdesc, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to bind socket! " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Listening with protocol TCP on port" << port << ".\n";

    if (listen(socketdesc, 3) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to listen on socket! " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (shutdown(socketdesc, SHUT_RDWR) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to close socket! " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    close(socketdesc);

    std::cout << "TCP test succeeeded.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `opt` need to be any specific value, or is it always 1?

Comment: @liaquore `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` take boolean integers as input, so they need to be set to 1 for on and 0 for off.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this answer here, even if it wasn't the case in this time. I think it's still a real case and someone looking for answers on the site might appreciate this.

( the real answer for the code above was in the comments )

---

You need to close the socket, You have not done so on every failure state. It will stay open and block you from binding to it again, even if the process ends.

If this is not the case, then you might have some other program using the port. Try changing the port number.

Comment: You do need to close sockets, but there is so such thing as 'opening it again', or being prevented from opening a socket by the existence of a prior socket. You seem to think a process can only open one socket.

Comment: I didn't mean that. Surely a process can have multiple sockets open at once. My point was that the socket stays alive outside the lifetime of your program, if you don't close it. This might cause problems if you are debugging a TCP server program and don't properly manage the sockets.

Comment: I changed "opening" to "binding" to avoid this confusion. Because you can have multiple sockets, but only one process can bind to a certain port.

Comment: All OSes that I've programmed for will close a socket after the process that opened it exits.  Another process may be prevented from reopening a socket on the same port for a while (on the order of minutes) but eventually the kernel will clean up everything and allow the socket/port to be opened again.